# How to insert value into manager list 2d with multiprocessing python

Tags: python, list, matrix, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing #Import multi-process module to achieve multi-process
import os #Verify, print the id of the process
import numpy as np #This module is for matrix multiplication
from multiprocessing import Manager, Lock
 
def matrix_muti(i,j,L,k):
    print('Current process is {0}'.format(os.getpid())) #Print the process when the function is executed
    A = [[12, 7, 3, 9, 10],
        [4, 5, 6, 8, 2],
        [7, 8, 9, 2, 0],
        [1, 2, 9, 0, 3],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
    B = [[5, 8, 1, 2, 9],
        [6, 7, 3, 0, 9],
        [7, 8, 9, 2, 0],
        [1, 2, 9, 0, 3],
        [4, 5, 9, 1, 3]]
    A = np.array(A)
    B = np.array(B)
    print(i,j)
    
    try:
        print(sum(A[i,:]*B[:,j]))
       
        if i==0:
            if j == 0:
                L.insert(0,[sum(A[i,:]*B[:,0])])
        
            elif (j>0):
                row = L[0]
                row.insert(j, sum(A[i,:]*B[:,j]))
                L[0] = row

        elif i==1:
            if j == 0:
                L.insert(1,[sum(A[i,:]*B[:,0])])
        
            elif (j>0):
                row1 = L[1]
                row1.insert(j, sum(A[i,:]*B[:,j]))
                L[1] = row1

        elif i==2:
            if j == 0:
                L.insert(2,[sum(A[i,:]*B[:,0])])
        
            elif (j>0):
                row2 = L[2]
                row2.insert(j, sum(A[i,:]*B[:,j]))
                L[2] = row2

        elif i==3:
            if j == 0:
                L.insert(3,[sum(A[i,:]*B[:,0])])
        
            elif (j>0):
                row3 = L[3]
                row3.insert(j, sum(A[i,:]*B[:,j]))
                L[3] = row3

        elif i==4:
            if j == 0:
                L.insert(4,[sum(A[i,:]*B[:,0])])
        
            elif (j>0):
                row4 = L[4]
                row4.insert(j, sum(A[i,:]*B[:,j]))
                L[4] = row4

    except:
        pass

 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()
    manager = Manager()
    lst = manager.list()
    m=1
    n=0
    print('parent process is {0}'.format(os.getpid())) #Get parent process id
    for i in range(25):
                                 #Control the row and column number changes of the matrix
        n=n+1             
        if n % 6 == 0:
            m = m + 1
            n = 1
 
    #Check whether the subscript change is correct
        print('Subscript change:',m-1,n-1)
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=matrix_muti,args=(m-1,n-1,lst,lock,)) #Fixed format, use 4 subprocesses to find the product of the matrix
        p.start() #Start
    p.join()
    print(lst)
```

So I want to create matrix multiplication with multiprocessing, and had all the element I want to insert into manager.list in that function, but not all of them was inserted or sometimes the element's index aren't right, what do I do with this

the result was like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a2nr.png)

But I want it to be like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSHTV.png)

Comment: The data insertion to a list cannot be parallelized but the sum-based computation can. You need to rework your algorithm to separate the two operation to be able to actually parallelize it. Regarding the work you do, consider using Numpy or Cython that are probably more well suited for that.

Comment: thank you for your answer sir